# getting errors when pip installing matplotlib

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pip, failed-installation

I am currently having an issue when I try to pip install matplotlib or some other packages in my environment. The exact error displayed is

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\b.wortmann\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7pmrrbge\contourpy_7debe2a9a1c24ff38219b2d21f02273f C:\Users\b.wortmann\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7pmrrbge\contourpy_7debe2a9a1c24ff38219b2d21f02273f\.mesonpy-awpd96gp\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\b.wortmann\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7pmrrbge\contourpy_7debe2a9a1c24ff38219b2d21f02273f\.mesonpy-awpd96gp\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\b.wortmann\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7pmrrbge\contourpy_7debe2a9a1c24ff38219b2d21f02273f
      Build dir: C:\Users\b.wortmann\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7pmrrbge\contourpy_7debe2a9a1c24ff38219b2d21f02273f\.mesonpy-awpd96gp\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: contourpy
      Project version: 1.1.0

      ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\b.wortmann\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7pmrrbge\contourpy_7debe2a9a1c24ff38219b2d21f02273f\.mesonpy-awpd96gp\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt    
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.        
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

I am using the latest version of the pip installer and setuptools. The python version I'm running is 3.10.6. I saw some similar issues for other packages, but none of the proposed solutions worked out for me.

I would be very graetfull if some can provide some help or usefull insights as I'm not getting where the error originates.

I tried to downgrade the versions of pip install, setuptools and python version in different constellations, in the hope it would work. One further thought was to look for dependencies that are needed, but as far as I know the installation of matplotlib should work with simple pip install command without further dependicies (or maybe I'm mistaking).

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: Do you have visual studio installed?

Comment: The failure seems obvious enough. It is telling you that you do not have the Visual Studio `vswhere.exe` program installed and that is a prerequisite to installing matplotlib from source. So either install that app or, as Trenton suggested, using Anaconda to install a prebuilt binary.